# Sim network speed issue inside house

Tags: networking, internet, mobile-phone, sim

I am from Pakistan and I am using Mobilink Jazz network. Signal strength of network is good and does best job for calling and sms but when using internet it slows down. When I get outside my house (just few meters away) internet works well but when I go inside house it becomes much slow. What's issue with my network or my mobile?

Comment: It is most likely just the local signal strength - coverage may be changed inside your house. Do you have other wireless inside your house?

Comment: Yes I have wifi connection.

Comment: The phone may be set to connect to both services and may possibly have some kind of conflict.